# Primefaces dataGrid dynamic number of columns depending on the display width

Tags: primefaces, datagrid

i'm using Primefaces 5.2.x
I implemented a dataGrid:

```
<p:dataGrid var="data" value="#{dataGrid.data}" columns="3" layout="grid" 
                        rows="12" paginator="true" id="dataview">
<f:facet name="header">
    Ihre Daten
</f:facet>
<p:commandLink update=":form:dataDetail" oncomplete="PF('dataDialog').show()" title="View Detail">
    <p:panel header="#{data.id}" style="text-align:center">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
            <h:outputText value="#{data.nummer}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{data.name}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{data.kurzname}" />
            <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="margin:0 auto;" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{data}" target="#{dataGrid.selectedData}" />
</p:commandLink></p:dataGrid>
```

This works so far.
But now i have always 3 panels in own row.
on iphone 6, on tablet, on desktop always 3 columns per row.
Only when I minimize the width strong. it breaks to show only one entry per row.

Now, i want that on mobile devices, like iphone, per default only one entry per row is shown. On tablets two and on desktop three.

How can i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should upgrade to the latest version of PrimeFaces.

Look here, and try it out. The Datagrid is responsive.

[DataGrid demo](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml)

Comment: It is indeed responsive, but 'fully responsive' is to much in my opinion. It does not have the option to configure 8, 5, 3 colums for different window sizes (as far as I know) This might however be nice addition. Maybe we should file an enhancement request.

Comment: you can tweak with CSS if the default behavior does not satisfy the requirements.

Comment: I know, but I could create a responsive datagrid with some divs, ui:repeat, some css etc too. ;-) Having it as part of a 'responsive' component would be even better.